# Where is the cache/temp storage for files being imported to the photos app?

Tags: macos, photos.app, path

I airdropped 90 photos over to my laptop (running Ventura 13.1) to the photos app, and on seeing them in the photos app, I absent-mindedly removed them from the iPad. Before I was able to click Import All Photos, the app hung due to something unrelated.

I was able to see in the sidebar under the devices column 'AEF0041A-9EDD-4BBE-..' - would that help any in locating the location unimported files would be located?

[#153661](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153661) Does not answer this question due to the folder mentioned in the answer no longer existing in modern versions, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Running out of RAM due to having too much going on with an image editor, several videos, etc. So, poor judgement, basically. Everything below 'Imported on' and to the right of the sidebar was pure pink, not even rendering anymore.

Comment: The cache folder only stores (low quality) thumbnails of what is to be imported, not the high res image.  Is your iPad backed up, either locally or via iCloud?  This will be your best bet at recovery

Comment: Is the cache in a new location now? It does not appear to be in the same location as the suggested previous solution.